# Cannot load database overlay due to permissions in OpenLDAP

Tags: permissions, overlay, acl, openldap

I am having a hard time to configure OpenLDAP with MemberOf overlay. I have compiled openldap 2.5.16 from scratch, with `--with-memberof` option. Somehow it works:

```command
sys# sbin/slapcat -F config/slapd.d -n 0
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}mdb
olcSuffix: dc=contoso,dc=com
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword  by anonymous auth  by self write  by * none
olcAccess: {1}to *  by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=contoso,dc=com" write  by self write  by * none
olcAddContentAcl: FALSE
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcLastBind: FALSE
olcMaxDerefDepth: 15
olcReadOnly: FALSE
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=contoso,dc=com
olcRootPW:: LKSkwema9kajkw32==
```

Now, as far as I understand, I need to load `memberof` overlay to database:

```command
sys# cat add_memberoff.ldif
dn: olcOverlay=memberof,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcMemberOf
olcOverlay: memberof
olcMemberOfRefint: TRUE
```

I'm trying to:

```command
bin/ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,dc=contoso,dc=com" -W -f add_memberoff.ldif
```

And I got:

```command
adding new entry "olcOverlay=memberof,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
```

In logs:

```command
65dca351.151db256 0x7eff2ffff6c0 conn=1028 fd=14 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:38524 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
65dca351.151e9d47 0x7eff34c016c0 conn=1028 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=contoso,dc=com" method=128
65dca351.1520796e 0x7eff34c016c0 conn=1028 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=contoso,dc=com" mech=SIMPLE bind_ssf=0 ssf=0
65dca351.15219d56 0x7eff34c016c0 conn=1028 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 qtime=0.000009 etime=0.000216 text=
65dca351.1523bd83 0x7eff2ffff6c0 conn=1028 op=1 ADD dn="olcOverlay=memberof,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
65dca351.1524555d 0x7eff2ffff6c0 => access_allowed: add access to "olcOverlay=memberof,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config" "entry" requested
65dca351.152486ca 0x7eff2ffff6c0 => acl_get: [1] attr entry
65dca351.1524a3c8 0x7eff2ffff6c0 => acl_mask: access to entry "olcOverlay=memberof,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config", attr "entry" requested
65dca351.1524b9ef 0x7eff2ffff6c0 => acl_mask: to all values by "cn=admin,dc=contoso,dc=com", (=0)
65dca351.1524d378 0x7eff2ffff6c0 <= check a_dn_pat: *
65dca351.1524f2cf 0x7eff2ffff6c0 <= acl_mask: [1] applying none(=0) (stop)
65dca351.15250d85 0x7eff2ffff6c0 <= acl_mask: [1] mask: none(=0)
65dca351.1525270d 0x7eff2ffff6c0 => slap_access_allowed: add access denied by none(=0)
65dca351.15253c3d 0x7eff2ffff6c0 => access_allowed: no more rules
65dca351.15258f10 0x7eff2ffff6c0 conn=1028 op=1 RESULT tag=105 err=50 qtime=0.000009 etime=0.000137 text=
65dca351.1526fba1 0x7eff34c016c0 conn=1028 op=2 UNBIND
65dca351.152a5b85 0x7eff34c016c0 conn=1028 fd=14 closed
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to perform this as `cn=admin,dc=contoso,dc=com`, as it states in the configuration. Off topic.

Comment: Look at the 3rd code sample. I am doing it as `cn=admin,dc=contoso,dc=com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Privileges ('olcRootDN' and 'olcAccess') are defined per-database. **You have two databases** – one for the `dc=contoso,dc=com` suffix, and one for the `cn=config` suffix.

Take a careful look at which one your LDIF is actually modifying: it says `dn: [...],cn=config`, therefore you must use an account (a bindDN) that has privileges to the `cn=config` database.

To find out which account you need, read the `olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config` entry. There are two commonly found variants:

- The database has its own superuser DN (olcRootDN), which is completely unrelated to the "main" database's olcRootDN. Often docker templates set it to `cn=admin,cn=config`.

  In this case you have to specify `-b cn=admin,cn=config` or similar, with the correct password too.
- The database grants local access to root (UID 0) through 'olcAccess', a lot like MariaDB/Postgres do these days. Look for an access entry that mentions "uidNumber=0...cn=external".

  In this case you have to make a local connection to `ldapi://` using SASL EXTERNAL bind mode – that is, using the option `-Y EXTERNAL` and **not** using the options `-x` or `-b`.